# How to vertically label confusion matrix in Latex

Tags: tables

actually I have two problems:

1. Need to label **Actuall Class** vertically in the confusion matrix with multiple rows (**see in picture blue pen)**?
2. The spaces between the columns are not equal (**see in picture Red Pen**)? Please tell me how can I equal the spaces between columns?
   Thanks in advance

```
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Confusion metric for ABC through Latex}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} cccccc||cccc}
            & & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Predicted Class} \\[2ex]
        \cline{2-10}
        &  &  & Feature grou 1  &  & &  & & Feature grou 2    &      \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table 
        \cline{2-10}
        &              & A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
        \cline{2-10}
     {\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual Class}}
        & A            & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
        & B           & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
        & C            & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --\\
        %\rot{\rlap{~General Class}}
        & D        & -- &  -- & --  & --  & --  & -- & -- & -- \\
        %\cmidrule[1pt]{2-12}
           \cline{2-10}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Actual Class}
\caption{Confusion metric for ABC through Latex}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} cc cccc|cccc}
        &  & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Predicted Class}         \\
        &  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Feature group 1}
                &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Feature group 2}      \\
        \cline{3-10}
        &              & A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D      \\
        \cline{3-10}
     \multirow{4}{*}[1ex]{\rothead {Actual Class}}
        & A     & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
        & B     & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
        & C     & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
        & D     & -- &  -- & --  & -- & --  & -- & -- & --  \\
           \cline{3-10}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually now I have a task to convert this into Elsevier latex format and in this format, the paper width for writing is short. So, the confusion matrix size is large in width, that's why it goes out of the Marjan page. What should I do to fix this error

Comment: the best is ask new question, where you provide new mwe with `elsevier` document class. meanwhile try if use of the `\small` font size and smaller `\tabcolsep` length (for example to 3pt) can help you.

Comment: where should I  add '\small' or '\tabcolsep'

Comment: `\tabcolsep` worked. Thank you so much <3

Comment: @NafeesAhmed, after `\begin{table}` and `before `\begin{tabular}`.